# Ti-Nspire cx calculator program will not execute

Tags: ti-basic

I'm having some difficulty making my new calculator run code.

Problems:
I follow tutorials but when I run my code it only responds with *Done* 
No output shows up

A photo to sum it up:

[image]

What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

A simple mistake - the command is Disp, not text.

Comment: thanks, but turns out the issue was simply that I needed to "save and check syntax" to save properly